# Why I got error of some methods that are not defined for dynamic links?

Tags: flutter, firebase, deep-linking

I am trying to create dynamic links for deep linking purpose, but I've been recieving these errors for 2 methods and I'm not sure why they generate errors because these methods are the ones used when I searched about dynamic links. Are there methods replacing them, or how should I correct the code?

Error messages:

> The method 'buildShortLink' isn't defined for the type 'DynamicLinkParameters'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'buildShortLink'.

> The method 'buildUrl' isn't defined for the type 'DynamicLinkParameters'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'buildUrl'.

Code:

```
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:firebase_dynamic_links/firebase_dynamic_links.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/providers/product_class.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class FirebaseDynamicLinkService{

  Future<String> _createDynamicLink(bool short, Product product) async {

    String _linkMessage='';
  bool _isCreatingLink = false;

    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://myapp.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse(
        'https://myapp/product?id=${product.documentID}',
      ),
   //   link: Uri.parse(DynamicLink),
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.example.myapp',
        minimumVersion: 125,
      ),
    );

    Uri url;
    if (short) {
      final ShortDynamicLink shortLink =
          await parameters.buildShortLink();  // here shows error
      url = shortLink.shortUrl;
    } else {
      url = await parameters.buildUrl(); // here shows error
    }

    return _linkMessage;
  }

}
```

I was expecting the code to not generate errors for these methods.

Comment: I am not familiar with `firebase_dynamic_links`, but [`buildShortLink`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_dynamic_links/latest/firebase_dynamic_links/FirebaseDynamicLinks/buildShortLink.html) is a method on `FirebaseDynamicLinks`, not on a [`DynamicLinkParameters`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface/latest/firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface/DynamicLinkParameters-class.html). `buildShortLink` takes a `DynamicLinkParameters` object as an *argument*.  I do not see any `buildUrl` method (although there is a `buildLink` method).

Answer (score 3):

you need to replace below code with suggested code

Replace this

```
if (short) {
      final ShortDynamicLink shortLink =
          await parameters.buildShortLink();  // here shows error
      url = shortLink.shortUrl;
    } else {
      url = await parameters.buildUrl(); // here shows error
    }
```

with this

```
if (short) {
      final ShortDynamicLink shortLink =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(parameters);  
      url = shortLink.shortUrl;
    } else {
      url = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(parameters);
    }
```

For more information , check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/create